# swift set value with switch will got error: expected initial value after '='

Tags: swift, switch-statement, nspredicate

I would wonder if there's any short cut way to set value of **colorPredicate**

enum Color {
        case black
        case white
    }

```
func predicateForColor(color: Color, compoundWith compoundPredicate: NSPredicate?) -> NSPredicate {

//  NOTE: if I use the code bellow to set the value of colorPredicate, will got error: expected initial value after '='.
//    let colorPredicate =
//        switch color {
//        case .black:   return predicateForBlack()
//        case .white:   return predicateForWhite()
//        }

    func getPredicateByColor(color: Color) -> NSPredicate {
        switch color {
        case .black:    return predicateForBlack()
        case .white:    return predicateForWhite()
        }
    }

    let colorPredicate = getPredicateByColor(color: color)

    if let predicate = compoundPredicate {
        return NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate, colorPredicate])
    } else {
        return colorPredicate
    }
}


func predicateForBlack() -> NSPredicate {
    print("get black predicate")
    return NSPredicate(format: "color = black")
}

func predicateForWhite() -> NSPredicate {
    print("get white predicate")
    return NSPredicate(format: "color = white & someother condition")
}


print(predicateForColor(color: .black, compoundWith: nil))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let colorPredicate: NSPredicate = { (color: Color) -> NSPredicate in
    switch color {
        case .black:   return predicateForBlack()
        case .white:   return predicateForWhite()
    }
}(color)
```

***update***

Your code produces an error because you need to write:

```
let variable = { switch { ... } }()
```

instead of

```
let variable = switch { ... }
```

so that you define a block and call it, you cannot assign from a switch statement.

***dictionary approach***

setup:

```
var lookup: [Color: NSPredicate] = [:]
lookup[.black] = NSPredicate(format: "color = black")
lookup[.white] = NSPredicate(format: "color = white")
```

use:

```
let colorPredicate = lookup[color]
```

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks for quick response. But still wonder why the commented code will give error.

Comment: Thanks, you answer is correct, I just hope to find an better way similar to let colorPredicate =  (color == .black)? predicateForBlack(): predicateForWhite()    this kind of shortcut way. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, you can do that, but it will only work for 2 cases. If you need more colours in future it will be better using the switch. But this works fine: let colorPredicate = (color == .black) ? predicateForBlack() : predicateForWhite()

Comment: Or you could add the predicates to a dictionary, there are different approaches, but I thought you just wanted to make the commented code work :)

Comment: No, I don't need an dictionary to get the value, which is similar way of nested function.  The block solution is the better choice for now :)